# Get SSL certificate from CSR file

Tags: java, rest, openssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am using certbot to generate trusted SSL certificate for my io.netty HTTP servers.

I’ve ran the following command:

```
$ sudo ./path/to/certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d 
www.example.com
```

Now I've got a csr file and a private key file:
   0000_csr-certbot.pem 0000_key-certbot.pem.

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to go from CSR to SSL certificate?

Comment: I assume you actually used a different domain name which you have registered and control, because you are prohibited from registering or controlling `example.com`. If it succeeded `certbot` should have left the certs (yours plus the required intermediate) in several files on your system; see https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates . If it didn't succeed, you should fix whatever problem caused the failure so it does succeed.

Comment: there was no error, still cant find /etc/letsencrypt/live directory

Answer (score 0):

You have to send that `CSR key` to the certificate authority to request the digital certificate.

You can follow this link: `https://in.godaddy.com/help/request-an-ssl-certificate-standard-assurance-31928`

Comment: To expand a bit just in case you are new to this. A csr file is required for a certification authority with the private key to issues a SSL certificate. Any certification authority or intermediaries(like Go-Daddy) will request this file in order to proceed. when you send it to them they will generate a certificate and send it back to you.

Comment: Except that certbot automatically sends the CSR to LetsEncrypt (which _is_ a CA) and gets the cert (plus chain) back -- that's its main purpose for existing.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 where can I get these cert ?